# Why can't my translation script handle cyrillic or chinese letters?

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm trying to build a really simple translating script for people who want to say something in their native language and get it translated into english. It works surprisingly well, but it cannot handle cyrillic (or chinese for example) letters at all.

```
if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("+t ")) {
        var args = message.content.substring(3).split(" ");
if(!args[0]) {
        message.channel.send("What do you want to translate?");
        return;
}
let gurl = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=english&dt=t&q=" + args.join("%20");
request(gurl, function(error, response, body) {
    try {
        let translated = body.match(/^\[\[\[".+?",/)[0];
        translated = translated.substring(4, translated.length - 2);
        message.delete().catch(O_o=>{});
        message.channel.send("**"+message.author.username+"** (via translator): " + translated);
    } catch(err) {
        message.channel.send("Failed: "+err);
    }
});

}
```

**err = TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined** if I try to translate them. Do I need to encode them somehow compatible to latin first or how should I approach the problem?

Comment: I really don't understand your question.. The splitting part shows in the code on the second line. It only gets rid of the prefix and - at first I decided to put the words into an array, right now it doesn't seem so useful since I decided to go for sentence translating but I don't plan to worry about details like that until I get the base working.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see that.

Comment: Could I affect the outcome by altering the regexp? Although it should print out english.. I'm lost - help me :D

Comment: Rather than assuming that any printable character can go into a URL (not a valid assumption with non-English characters) and that only space needs to be encoded by `%20` leave the entire string as is and do an encodeURIComponent. You can use any of the modules on npm to do `%` encoding of URI component. You'd be surprised how many things need `%` encoding - not just `%20`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! I got it working with your tips.